# What data should in I store in a session variable in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I am new to laravel. I have been working on a laravel 5 app with different types of users. I need information about which type of user is currently logged in different sections of my views:

Currently, I have been doing something like below on various controller methods and with the user object, I can determine which type of user it is in my view:

In Controller:

```
public function someMethod(){
    $user = Auth::user();
    return view('applications.show', compact('user'));
}
```

In View:

```
if($user->is_manager)
   // do this
else if($user->is_admin)
  // do that
```

Because I need information about the user-type in various views, I have been calling `Auth::user()` in several places and I am beginning to think that this is adding some load on the DB. Is it better to store the user-type in a session variable and what kind of data should I be storing in my session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't be an issue storing it in the session.

In the `is_manager` function in your `User` class, you could do something like the following...

```
public function is_manager()
{
    // Check if the session has been set first.
    if(\Session::has('is_manager')) {
        return \Session::get('is_manager');
    }

    // Do your necessary logic to determine if the user is a manager, ex...
    $is_manager = $this->roles()->where('name', '=', 'manager')->count() == 1;

    // Drop it in the session
    \Session::put('is_manager', $is_manager);

    return $is_manager;
}
```

Keep in mind if your session driver is set to database, then this obviously isn't going to help.

Comment: Thanks for the input @user3158900. Why is it not going to help if the session driver is set to database.

Comment: Because you are worried about the load on the database.  If you set your session handler to database, you will still be making those calls, just to a different table.

Comment: Wow. Logical thinking @user3158900. My session driver is file and everything has been working just fine. Are they any potential advantage of using database handler.

Answer (score 0):

We have organized common model calls as follows;

- Base classes for controllers, models, libraries, composers, commands and jobs which get these models. All related classes extend from these base classes thus have everything they have.
- Master view composer to serve as base data gatherer for all views.
- Query caching through Redis. All the above classes get the user through a cached query with timeout of an hour thus the query is executed only once per hour per user.