# How long does data last in session in laravel?

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5

Recently, I have noticed a very disturbing situation with my laravel 5 app which I can't seem to figure out. During login, I set the user_type variable in session like so

```
Session::put('is_supervisor', $user->is_supervisor);
```

In my config/session.php file, I have the following configuration:

```
'lifetime' => 120,
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

I have also implemented the remember me functionality.

I logged in as a supervisor user with remember me checked. After a few hours, I close the browser without logging out and launch again which logged into the user profile as expected since `expire_on_close` was set to false and remember me was checked. But, I notice that the is_supervisor variable didn't exist any more in session so I had to logout and login again to have the variable back in session. What could be the problem? I am using file as my session driver.

Comment: This is one of those questions where the question answers the question. Thanks ;)

Comment: you have a good imagination

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to understand what happened: You've set the lifetime of the sessions to 120 minutes, which means after 120 minutes the session is flushed.

The `remember_me` feature is using cookies. If there is no user session Laravel checks the cookies and recreates the session if the session cookie is still valid.

My question for you is: Why do you store this data in a session? If you want to check if a user is a supervisor just do `if ($user->is_supervisor)`.

If there is some db query that happens inside the `is_supervisor` function then use some caching mechanism.

Comment: Thanks @amir-bar for your input. Please check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165233/what-data-should-in-i-store-in-a-session-variable-in-laravel-5/ for why I store the data on session. I used 'user3158900' approach.

Comment: yes he gave you a good answer, why you are not using it? if the data is not in the session than do the logic and insert in the session again, than what problem you have?

Comment: Actually I used his approach

Comment: public function is_supervisor(){

        // Check if the session has been set first.
        if(Session::has('is_supervisor')) {
            return Session::get('is_supervisor');
        }

        // Do your necessary logic to determine if the user is a manager, ex...
        $is_supervisor = $this->is_supervisor;

        // Drop it in the session
        if($is_supervisor)
            Session::put('is_supervisor', $is_supervisor);

        return $is_supervisor;
    }

Comment: Now @amir bar I have some logic like this in view `@if(session('is_admin') || session('is_super_admin'))
                <li><a href="{{ url('internship_extensions') }}" >Extension Application</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ url('interns/new') }}" >New</a></li>
            @endif`

Comment: with his approach you don't use the session to check access, you need to call the function if($user->is_supervisor()) . the function iteself is dealing with the sessions.. so if you have is_super_admin than make a new function to check against that

Comment: I see your point. You know I have been using middleware in the constructor of each controller to control access. So it is  the middleware that calls the is_supervisor() method defined in the User Model and sets the variable in session hence why I can just use the session variable to control access in view.

Comment: but why use the session if you have function for that? use the function

Comment: If the middleware is called in the constructor, then the session variable would've already been set before we ever get to the view hence I can just easily check the session.

Comment: but why would you do that? can you give a good reason? I am not 100%(need to check) but it may be possible that in the cunstructor call the session was vaild, but later in the view the session got deleted and than we are back to the same problem

Comment: I ve a middleware with a handle function as: `if(!$request->user()->is_supervisor()){ flash()->warning('not allowed.'); return redirect('dashboard');}`. It calls e is_supervisor fxn defined above which sets e session if it doesn't exist. This middleware is called in the constructor which sets e value in e session if it didn't exist. So if later, e session got deleted in the view it means e user would've been idle for 2 hrs n so if he refreshes the page, a controller would still be called which will set e value again in session.

Comment: ok do whatever you want its your code.. so what is the problem if everything is working fine, I gave you an answer its lasts for the lifetime value in your config

Comment: I will try to debug and see what is missing. Thank you so much for your contribution @amir-bar. Actually your answer helped me to understand how the session works. With your approach, would it be possible to call the is_supervisor function in the model from the view. Because depending on the user type, I display different things in my view.

Comment: yes because you declared the function inside the user model you do $user->is_supervisor()

Comment: It means I would need to get the Auth::user and pass the user object to every view where I need to know information about which type of user is logged in.

Comment: if you want to know if user is admin, than you need to know who the user is, no matter what you doing, so yes you will need to do Auth::user() in every request, but dont worry to much about it, also just so you know you already call that function in the middlewar I think you need to read about the basic stuff first

Comment: Ok. I see. If you looked at my other question, you would notice that this is the approach I wanted to take but gave up because I had to do Auth::user in every method that I needed user info. Anyway, I have two options now. thanks

Comment: as I told you, there is no problem in doing Auth::user in every method you need to understand that laravel will not query the db every time, only the first call will make query than it just got it from cache

Comment: Great. I've got some changes to make here. It means I don't really need those variables in session. You've been really helpful.

Comment: Hello @amir-bar. I see the point you were trying to make the whole time. Works well. Sorry.